# obtener numero de telefono propio con react-native

Tags: react-native, programación-móvil

Desarrollando mi app con **react-native**, debo obtener el número de telefono del celular en que se esta ejecutando la app. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea para eso? ¿Como lo harian ustedes y por que?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí es posible, mediante la librería https://github.com/pocesar/react-native-sim-data

La instalas mediante los comandos:

```
npm i react-native-sim-data
react-native link react-native-sim-data
```

Lo importas en tu código:

```
import RNSimData from 'react-native-sim-data'
```

Y obtienes los datos de la SIM mediante la función:

```
RNSimData.getSimInfo()
```

El objeto que obtienes tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
{
  carrierName0: string;
  displayName0: string;
  countryCode0: string;
  mcc0: string;
  mnc0: string;
  isNetworkRoaming0: string;
  isDataRoaming0: string;
  simSlotIndex0: string;
  phoneNumber0: string;
  deviceId0: string;
  simSerialNumber0: string;
  subscriptionId0: string;
}
```

Para obtener el número de teléfono sería:

```
RNSimData.getSimInfo().phoneNumber0;
```

NOTA: El número 0 que ves en las propiedades hace referencia a la cantidad de SIM que tenga tu dispositivo, si tu teléfono es SIM Dual puedes obtener el número de teléfono de ambos cambiando 0 por 1.

Comment: Excelente. Muchas Gracias David

Comment: De nada para eso estamos¡¡